# python 3.11 cannot set value for SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.extensions_map

Tags: python-3.x, webserver

Python SimpleHTTPRequestHandler cannot server yaml as content type.

I try to run a python web server as helm charts repo. I need to set yaml files as content type (text/yaml or text/x-yaml).

Here is my code:

```
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8000
DIRECTORY = "web"

class Handler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    extensions_map={
        '.yaml': 'text/x-yaml',
        '.manifest': 'text/cache-manifest',
        '.html': 'text/html',
        '.png': 'image/png',
        '.jpg': 'image/jpg',
        '.svg': 'image/svg+xml',
        '.css': 'text/css',
        '.js':  'application/x-javascript',
        '': 'application/octet-stream', # Default
    }
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, directory=DIRECTORY, **kwargs)
        self.extensions_map={
            '.yaml': 'text/x-yaml',
            '.manifest': 'text/cache-manifest',
            '.html': 'text/html',
            '.png': 'image/png',
            '.jpg': 'image/jpg',
            '.svg': 'image/svg+xml',
            '.css': 'text/css',
            '.js':  'application/x-javascript',
            '': 'application/octet-stream', # Default
        }
Handler.extensions_map={
    '.yaml': 'text/x-yaml',
    '.manifest': 'text/cache-manifest',
    '.html': 'text/html',
    '.png': 'image/png',
    '.jpg': 'image/jpg',
    '.svg': 'image/svg+xml',
    '.css': 'text/css',
    '.js':  'application/x-javascript',
    '': 'application/octet-stream', # Default
}

# h=Handler
# print(h.extensions_map)

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

When I click yaml file in the website, webserver does not show content of it, but shows download option.

Answer (score 0):

The browser has cache. If I use a new port the browser shows content directly.

```py
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8001
DIRECTORY = "web"
 
class YamlHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, directory=DIRECTORY, **kwargs)

YamlHandler.extensions_map={
    '.yaml': 'text/x-yaml',
    '.manifest': 'text/cache-manifest',
    '.html': 'text/html',
    '.png': 'image/png',
    '.jpg': 'image/jpg',
    '.svg': 'image/svg+xml',
    '.css': 'text/css',
    '.js':  'application/x-javascript',
    '': 'application/octet-stream', # Default
}

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), YamlHandler) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.allow_reuse_address=1
    httpd.serve_forever()
```